# Redirect IP address and Subdomain to HTTPS Domain

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

**Redirect** **IP** **address** and **Subdomain** to **HTTPS** **Domain** with an **.htaccess** file?

`https://176.9.11.218`

`https://176.9.11.218:443`

`https://mail.pooeen.com/`

Please **Redirect** to the **Domain** **address** below.

`https://www.pooeen.com/`

**Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead**

Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to **176.9.11.218**. If you visit this site, attackers could try to steal information like your passwords, emails, or credit card details.

I am looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Thank you in advance for invaluable co-operation.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^176\.9\.11\.218
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.pooeen.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pooeen\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^176\.9\.11\.218 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail\.pooeen\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.pooeen.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you try to connect to an HTTPS url containing hostname H then one of the subject alternative names in the certificate must be H. There's no way to get around that rule, in particular you can't get around that rule by using HTTP redirects.